# jQuery select and apply style

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a lot of td cells. Each of the cells might have a one or more divs inside. I need to take first inner div's inline style and **move it** to the parent td's style.

How can this be done in jQuery?

Comment: Is applying "inline styles" only good enough?

Comment: Do you mean `style` attribute, class or all CSS properties?

Comment: By applying, do you mean "also applying" or moving the style from the `<div>` to its parent `<td>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple:

```
$('td div').each(function() {
  $(this).closest('td').attr('style', $(this).attr('style'));
});
```

Comment: The div has already the css style that needs to be passed to the td.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('td').find('div:first').each(function() {
   $(this).closest('td').attr('style', $(this).attr('style'));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

To apply the first div style only:

```
$('td div:first-child').each(function(){
    $(this).parent('td').attr('style', $(this).attr('style'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to get the computed style instead of the explicit style-argument of the div-element. There are few questions trying to find an answer in StackOverflow already

1. [jQuery CSS plugin that returns computed style of element to pseudo clone that element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004475/jquery-css-plugin-that-returns-computed-style-of-element-to-pseudo-clone-that-ele)
2. [How can I programmatically copy all of the style attributes from one DOM element to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715447/how-can-i-programmatically-copy-all-of-the-style-attributes-from-one-dom-element)

The solutions provide two ways to deal with this: either create a list of style properties you want to copy and iterate over them with `parentTd.css(property, childDiv.css(property))` or use the computedStyle provided by the browser. Unfortunately the latter is not supported in Internet Explorer and needs a workaround.

Comment: Started to browse before the clarification for inline style. I'll leave the comment so that others may be lead to the solutions to the more complicated scenario.